# How can I edit the Amazon RDS ssl_ca_file parameter?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, amazon-rds

I want to require connections to my RDS instance to use TLS/SSL, and to authenticate using a client certificate attested to by a CA I control. I understand I can do the former by modifying my instance's parameter group and setting `rds.force_ssl=1`. As for the latter, I believe I need to update the CA cert used by my database. I see that there is a parameter, `ssl_ca_file` with the value `/rdsdbdata/rds-metadata/ca-cert.pem`. However, I don't understand how to access that file or modify the parameter.

Unfortunately I haven't found anything in the AWS docs on this topic. Has anyone successfully done something like this?

Answer (score 1):

RDS is a managed service. You can't modify the ca-cert.pem file.

> and to authenticate using a client certificate attested to by a CA I control

That is not something RDS supports at this time.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder why they even list it as a parameter if it can't be edited